# How do I count the total of numbers?

Tags: php, php-5.3

I am looking for a way to get the sum of a values.
I have this `<nbsection>2</nbsection><nbsection>4</nbsection>`

So I do this loop to get the values of the nbsection but I don't have the sum:

```
$countvaluesection=0;

foreach($getneb as $clé=>$value){

    $countvaluesection+=$value->nbsection)
    var_dump($countvaluesection)

}
```

I have on var_dump 2 and 4, not the total. How can I get the total?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the contents of `$getneb`?

Comment: so it's table  contains the infos from XML

Comment: Well the code looks fine. If the data is as you describe, it should work. Without seeing the data, its impossible to help further im afraid

Comment: i need the count of this value 2 and 4 it 's not calculated

Answer (score 0):

That can't be your code because you have multiple syntax errors. This has an end paren without a beginning paren and is missing a semicolon:

```
$countvaluesection+=$value->nbsection)
```

This is missing a semicolon:

```
var_dump($countvaluesection)
```

This works just fine:

```
$countvaluesection = 0;

foreach($getneb as $clé => $value){
    $countvaluesection += $value->nbsection;
}
```

Given that `$value` has a property `nbsection` that is a numerical value. Under no circumstances would the value of `nbsection` be assigned to `$countvaluesection` when you're using the `+=` operator.

Comment: so if i have juste one <nbsection> balise i do this test if (isset($value->nbsection)){ just put the vaulue of the onse nbsection else the total sum of the nbsection

Comment: If you have just one `<nbsection>` you wouldn't have to check because the sum of 1 element value is the same as that element value.